# How can i analyze width and length of multiple plant pods in single image using ImageJ software?

Tags: imagej

Ihave tried to analyze the images of plant pods using ImageJ software but it does not show the width and length of a pod/pods accurately. Because the pods are curved, it gives the width of a pod upto 5 to 8 cm which should be below 1 cm. Can anyone suggest me exactly how we can measure the width and length of only black portions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide a reference scale. Without it, your results will be in pixels not cm or mm!

The rightmost pod results in the following values:

OrthoMedial-Distances (widths)

```
Mean = 52.65±8.39px;
Median = 55.97px;
MinMax = (10.5, 61.5)px;
```

Medial-Axis

```
Length = 1785.0px;
```

EDIT:
The analysis was done using the ImageJ-plugins "Easy_EdgeTrace.class" for tracing and and "general_TraceDistances.class" for the width and length evaluation. Both can be accessed [from here](https://www.gluender.de/Miscellanea/MiscTexts/UtilitiesText.html#Gl-2021-1).
Make sure the pods are suitably oriented. The tracing won't work properly for pod #3.
Here is what I get for the rightmost pod: [image: Tracing & Medial Axis]
Here are the widths: [image: Plot of the Widths]

OrthoMedial-Distances (widths):

```
Mean = 0.69±0.11cm;
Median = 0.73cm;
MinMax = (0.13, 0.81)cm;
```

Medial-Axis:

```
Length = 23.90cm;
```

Comment: I have added the reference scale. Can you please tell me how to do it? @Herbie